# re-size my image without blur

Tags: android

I am making an app to capture image by using intent and re-sizing image according to me but it is blurred after being captured so I need to take suggestions and help.
Actually I am re-sizing picture by scale "create Scaled Bitmap" and want to covert image in small size but after re-sizing in small size being blurred.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                if (data != null && data.getExtras() != null && data.getExtras().get("data") != null) {
                    bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
                    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
                    int newWidth = 100;
                    int newHeight = 50;
                    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
                    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    // resize the bit map
                    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
                    // rotate the Bitmap

                    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

                    int h = resizedBitmap.getHeight();

                    int b = resizedBitmap.getWidth();
                    Log.e("height & width ", h + "" + b);

                    Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 25, 25, true);

                    int h1 = bitmap.getHeight();
                    int b1 = bitmap.getWidth();
                    Log.e("height 1  & width  1", h1 + "" + b1);

                    mbPhotoImageViewId.setImageBitmap(resized);
                    int size = resized.getWidth() * resized.getHeight();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(size);
                    resized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

                    byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
                    System.out.println("byte array:" + image.length + "   " + image);

                    img_str = Base64.encodeToString(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    System.out.println("string: " + img_str.length() + "   " + img_str);

                    Log.d("BITMAP form of image", image.toString());

                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Error Code : C_M09004", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in this code you have to pass your desire height and width according to this height and width this function resize image

```
public Bitmap Resizedoesnotlosequality(String tempDir, int reqwid,
        int reqhei) {

    Bitmap src = null;

    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempDir, bmpFactoryOptions);

        BitmapFactory.Options Options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        Options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(bmpFactoryOptions,
                reqwid, reqhei);
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempDir, Options);

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // resize the bit map

        // recreate the new Bitmap
        bmpwid = bm.getWidth();
        bmphei = bm.getHeight();
        src = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(),
                matrix, true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return src;
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        while ((height / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                || (width / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize++;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;

}
```